# Perl syntax error printing list index

Tags: perl

I am trying to print an index of a list returned from a function call.  I am wrapping the function call in parenthesis in an attempt to convert the list to an array.  The program fails to compile saying 'syntax error at file.pl line 4, near ")["'.  If I create a temporary variable $a or use printf indexing is fine.  Why does print brake, is there a better alternative?

```
sub get{
    return (1,2);
}
#print (get())[0]; #fails
printf("%d",(get())[0]);
my $a = (get())[0];
print $a;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you are foolishly not using

```
use warnings;
```

Which is quite a bad thing to not do. If you had used it, you would get the warning:

```
print (...) interpreted as function
```

Which is to say, what you wrote

```
print (get())[0]
```

Is something Perl interprets as you trying to put a subscript on the `print()` function. This does not work.

For the code to do what you expect, you need to be explicit about the parentheses:

```
print ( (get())[0] );
```

You should always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

There is a slight learning curve to using these, but they only show you your errors. Not using them only hides your errors, and your code does not work better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sub get{
    return (1,2);
}
print((get)[0]);
```

or

```
my $a = (get)[0];
print $a;
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1
```